# 401 (Unauthorised) response from Pusher due to failed authentication with Sanctum

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-echo, laravel-sanctum, pusher-js

Getting a 401 (Unauthorised) response from Pusher due to failed authentication using Laravel Sanctum.

`[Error] Pusher :  : ["Error: Unable to retrieve auth string from channel-authorization endpoint - received status: 401 from http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth. Clients must be authorized to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/authorizing-users/"]`

The `BroadcastServiceProvider` is using Sanctum authentication guard.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']]);

        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

On the frontend `X-CSRF-TOKEN` is being passed in the header. I've tried changing this header to `Bearer` and `Authorization` but still getting the same 401 unauthorized response.

```js
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
import Pusher from 'pusher-js'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export default async function echo() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        Pusher.logToConsole = true

        // const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')

        const key = '<redacted>'

        const pusherClient = new Pusher(key, {
            cluster: 'eu',
            forceTLS: true,
            channelAuthorization: {
                endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000/broadcasting/auth',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN'),
                },
            },
        })

        window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'pusher',
            client: pusherClient,
        })

        window.Echo.private('chat').listen(
            'App\\Events\\PrivateMessageSent',
            e => {
                console.log(e)
            },
        )
    }
}
```